# Docker permission issue when mounting volumes on an encrypted llvm partition?

Tags: docker, permissions, llvm

I run a Fedora distribution. My `/home` is an encrypted volume.
When mounting files or directories as volume with docker using the `-v` option or through the `volumes` directory in a `docker-compose.yml` file I get very weird permissions on the file :

```
$ touch ~/test
$ docker run -v /home/jkr/test:/test -it --rm nginx bash
$ root@65fcd1754a1d:/# ls -la /
ls: cannot access '/test': Permission denied
total 84
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 4096 Aug 30 20:29 .
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 4096 Aug 30 20:29 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root    0 Aug 30 20:29 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 bin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Jun 13 10:30 boot
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root  360 Aug 30 20:29 dev
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 4096 Aug 17 11:46 docker-entrypoint.d
-rwxrwxr-x.   1 root root 1202 Aug 17 11:45 docker-entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 4096 Aug 30 20:29 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Jun 13 10:30 home
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 4096 Aug 17 11:46 lib
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 490 root root    0 Aug 30 20:29 proc
drwx------.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 root
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 run
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root    0 Aug 30 20:16 sys
-??????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? test
drwxrwxrwt.   1 root root 4096 Aug 17 11:46 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 4096 Aug 16 00:00 var
```

Notice the permission of the `/test` file inside the docker

`-??????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? test`

If I create this `test` file on a non encrypted llvm volume e.g. in `/opt/` or `/tmp` then the permission is correct.

Is there any way to mount docker volume on an encrypted partition ?

Comment: I just noticed that `sudo setenforce 0` solves the issue. This does not explain why the permission shows `?` but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

`-` means its regular file , when this file is created then which user are use this permission maybe this user is deleted but file is exists thats why `??` is showing